# Is it possible to move a view to the bottom-left-most corner in a LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

So, this is my View

[image]

with the XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView
        style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/crime_title_label" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/crime_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/crime_title_hint" />

    <TextView
        style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/crime_details_label" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/crime_date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/crime_solved"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/crime_solved_label" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I wanted to add a Button to the bottom-left-most corner. But I am not sure if that is achievable in a vertical orientated Linear Layout. The only way that comes to my mind without changing the layout type is to add this part to the Button I want: `android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"` but that does not do the trick. Any suggestions? I would be happy if it could be solved in Linear Layout.

Comment: Replace the linear layout with a relative layout and you should be able to do this easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the shortest solution, although I cannot think of anything not including additional layout. Add it at the end of your xml (still in the LinearLayout).

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: May I ask why this works? How come it displayed in the very bottom in a Linear Layout? Thanks.

Comment: Sure. In this way you make the FrameLayout size the rest of the view. As it is transparent, the user cannot see it. And then you put button in it with parameter layout_gravity=bottom to let the parent of button know that its child wants to be at the bottom.